# Check if a record has all of the values of IN operator

Tags: mysql, sql, join

There are three tables which are like this:

```
S  (sid, sname, scity)
P  (pid, pname, color, weight)
SP (sid, pid, quantity)
```

The question is to *return those sname(s) which has(have) all of the pid(s) with blue color*

At first I wrote this one:

```
SELECT S.sname FROM S INNER JOIN SP ON S.sid = SP.sid 
INNER JOIN P ON SP.pid = P.pid 
WHERE color = 'blue';
```

which of course is not right, because it returns those sname(s), even it has just one P with blue color.

My second query is this one:

```
SELECT S.sname FROM S INNER JOIN SP ON S.snum = SP.snum 
INNER JOIN P ON SP.pnum = P.pnum 
WHERE SP.pnum IN
(SELECT pnum FROM P WHERE color != 'blue');
```

This is also not right, because it seems that `IN` operator acts like multiple `OR` conditions.
Would you please let me know how can I set a condition which instead of `OR`, acts like `AND`?

Comment: This is relational division & is a faq.. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `WHERE P.pnum = ANY (SELECT pnum FROM P WHERE color = 'blue')` to Gorden's answer and of course added another `join`.
So the complete query is this one which works perfect for the question.

```
SELECT S.sname 
FROM S INNER JOIN SP ON
   S.snum = SP.snum 
      INNER JOIN P ON 
      SP.pnum = P.pnum 
WHERE P.pnum = ANY (SELECT pnum FROM P WHERE color = 'blue')
GROUP BY S.sname 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SP.pnum)
 = 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P WHERE color = 'blue');
```

Answer (score 2):

> The question is to return those sname(s) which has(have) all of the pid(s) with blue color

I think you want `group by` and `having`.  I think this is what you want:

```
select sp.sid
from sp join
     p
     on sp.pid = p.pid
where p.color = 'blue'
group by sp.sid
having count(distinct sp.pid) = (select count(*) from p p2 where p2.color = 'blue');
```

This returns the `sid`.  You can get the name with an additional `joi`n.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for your reply. But this query focuses on the count rather than the pid's with specific color. For example it returns true if the amount of green P are the same as blue

Comment: @drdn . . . So?  Your question is only about the blue color, not whether or not there are any greens.